# Could a computer round the same floating point number into two different directions?

Tags: node.js, floating-point, precision

I'm using Node.JS to run my Philips Hue lightstrip and have it match relative brightness and color temperature of the sun throughout the day, and the system is designed to run every 5 seconds and cut the program if detects a change between each loop. I achieve this through setting the color temp and brightness equal to the output of an equation where x is the current time, and obviously these return floats

I'm currently telling the program to just round to the nearest number and then set that rounded number as the temp/brightness, then record into another variable that setting (straight from the bulb, not the variable), and then next loop see if that variable matches the bulbs settings. If its different, it was manually changed so it cuts off the program so I can set the bulb to what I want

But I've had a few issues where on the next loop, before the bulb gets updated (so it should be the same value), its reading that the current settings are +-1 from the last recorded setting. And I'm wondering if this may be due to the number actually rounding in two different directions, such that when it sets the number its rounded down, but when recording the output the computer estimation actually sets it a little bit too high and rounds up instead

TL;DR: I set a value with a rounded floating point, I recorded the setting that should be the same, it ends up +-1 of the value it was supposedly set to

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, its not due to floating point errors, its because I'm using setInterval for every 5000ms, and it doesn't finish the call to the lights sometimes before it calls the next loop, leading to it adjusting the value of the lights before saving the value, so it ends up on the next loop expecting an old value. The solution is to find another way to loop every 5 seconds aside from setInterval

Comment: 5000ms should be plenty enough to get the data back from the bridge though

Comment: Yea I'd think so, but for some reason it kept erroring out soon after starting until I changed it up to 15 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You need an async function instead of using setInterval.

I'm a NodeJS noob so can't be exact, but here's a javascript example that will wait 5 seconds between requests but will wait if the request doesn't resolve within 5 seconds

```
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function hue() {
    let response = await fetch('http://url.to/hue/');
    if (response.status == 200) {
    let json = await response.json();
    return json;
  }
}
let poll = true;
while (poll) {
    let lightstrip = await Promise.all([
        hue().then(response => console.log(response)),
        timeout(5000)
    ]);
}
```